# Не увеличивается контейнер по высоте при добавлении элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток. Имеется div у которого высота 100% с ID container. У BODY и HTML высота тоже 100%. Но при добавлении элементов через JQuery методом .append() они просто вылезают за рамку контейнера. Контейнер при этом не увеличивается по высоте.

```
<body>
<div id="container" align="center">
<span>
<input type=text id=opt_0 class=additional>
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
JQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
ifIssetAddForm();})
ifIssetAddForm(){
if($('.additional').length>0){
$('.additional').keyup(function(event){
if($(this).val()!=''){
var edID=(this.id.replace(/\D/g,''))*1;
if($('#opt_'+(edID+1)).length<=0){
var main_elem=$('#opt_'+edID).parent();
var new_elem=$(main_elem).clone();
var new_input=$(new_elem).children('input');
edID++;
$(new_input).removeAttr('id').attr('id','opt_'+edID);
$('#container').append(new_elem);
}
```

Comment: у body есть внутренний отступ

Comment: добавьте код,хотябы,  который уже есть

Comment: Не зафлоачены ли элементы которые вы там добавляете? Нужен код.

Comment: элементы не зафлоачены.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать `min-height` для `div` и убрать `height` и вообще проверьте куда, собственно, добавляются элементы. Может они не туда попадают

Comment: Это не помогло. Высота у дива вообще не задана. Но я пробовал и 100% ее делать. Все равно не изменяется. Элементы помещаются в контейнер. Но высота контейнера остаётся такая же как и при первой загрузки страницы